# I am trying to call a defined function inside of an if statement and I am getting an error

Tags: python, function, tabs, spaces, replit

I am using python to run my code and I've tried all the debuging I could think of but I am still getting an error.

```
SubOrSuper = input("\nWould you like to translate a \033[1msubscript\033[0m, or a \033[1msuperscript?\033[0m\n")

  if SubOrSuper == "subscript" :
    TransToSuper = input ("\nInput your subscript here: ")
        TTSup()

#Subscript to Superscript translating process
def TTSup() :
    if TransToSuper == "H" :
        Hsub()
```

Error:

```
File "main.py", line 141
  TTSup()
        ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces  in indentation
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
SubOrSuper = input("\nWould you like to translate a \033[1msubscript\033[0m, or a \033[1msuperscript?\033[0m\n")

  if SubOrSuper == "subscript" : #Here you have two extra spaces that should not be. Your if has a wrong indent, and should not have at all
    TransToSuper = input ("\nInput your subscript here: ")
        TTSup() #There is no need to indent here, you did above after the If

#Subscript to Superscript translating process
def TTSup() :
    if TransToSuper == "H" :
        Hsub() #Here you did indent correctly
```

Corrected code:

```
SubOrSuper = input("\nWould you like to translate a \033[1msubscript\033[0m, or a \033[1msuperscript?\033[0m\n")

if SubOrSuper == "subscript" :
    TransToSuper = input ("\nInput your subscript here: ")
    TTSup()

#Subscript to Superscript translating process
def TTSup() :
    if TransToSuper == "H" :
        Hsub()
```

As said in comment, when the error message says:

```
File "main.py", line 141
  TTSup()
        ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces  in indentation
```

It means: there is an `inconsistent use of tabs and spaces  in indentation` at `line 141`.

So you need to work on that line. If you have no clue, remove it, see if it works. If it does work, add it back in any different way you can think about (and once again, if you don't understand / could not find any answers on the web). When, finally, it works, you should have understood why by inspecting the difference from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to remove that one tab before TTSup() function call. And you will be good.